# Trying to remove a sublayer causes terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: objective-c, calayer

I'm adding a gradient layer and attaching name to it.
Later on when I try to remove it by searching for that name, my app crashes. Here's the code I'm using.

```
CAGradientLayer* gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   ..... setting up gradient.....
gradientLayer.name      = @"GradientLayer";

[self.myView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Later on I'm trying to remove it.

```
for (CALayer *layer in self.myView.layer.sublayers) {
        if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"GradientLayer"])
        {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
        }
    }
```

It crashes when it tries to remove the sublayer.

Comment: Could you show the full crash error message? It may contain important information piece of information about the crash.

Comment: This is all I get - libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint or try to reproduce the issue in a small test project. My guess: "Collection was mutated while being enumerated".

Comment: @PriteshDesai Are you sure you didn't get "***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason:" ... "was mutated while being enumerated." message in console? Because if that's the answer is the correct one, you should have get it. It's important to locate the correct and full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop mutates `self.myView.layer.sublayers` while it is being enumerated.

Add `break;` after `[layer removeFromSuperLayer];` to stop enumerating, then you will be fine.